# extract substring using regex

Tags: regex

I would like to extract the string between `"t="` and `'&'` from the string below, but `'&2384'` may not be present sometimes. I have tried the following, but I get the result `"123455asdfgh&2384"` instead of `"123455asdfgh"`, what am I doing wrong here? thanks for help.

```
$string="t=123455asdfgh&2384";
$match=array();

preg_match('/t=(.*)(&.*)?/', $string, $match);

echo $match[1];
```

NOTE: I need to use regular exp...

Comment: You don't *need* to use a regular expression. You *want* to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one instead

```
preg_match('/t=([^&]*)(&.*)?/', $string, $match);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a non greedy quantifier:

```
preg_match('/t=(.*?)(?=&|$)/', $string, $match);
```

The problem is that the first `.*` matches everything up till the end of the string, which is still a complete match because the latter group is optional.

Comment: @bingjie2680 Have a look at this live demo: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/wtd-zkr It seems to working exactly the way you asked.

Answer (score 1):

This is better suited for  [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str), and not a regex.

```
parse_str( "t=123455asdfgh&2384", $params);
echo $params['t'];
```

This [prints](http://3v4l.org/6OceG#v430):

```
123455asdfgh
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what `parse_str` is for (parsing query strings):

```
$string="t=123455asdfgh&2384";
$args = array();
parse_str($string, $args);
echo $args['t']; // outputs '123455asdfgh'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the [`strpos()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to find the starting and ending point in the string, and then extract it?